# How can I link to a phone call link from within an embedded web page in Android?

Tags: android, webview, protocols, telephony

I have an Android application that has one section loading a web page within a frame of the app.

On the webpage, it has a link to call our support line using the `tel:123456` protocol (i.e. `<a href="tel:123456"><img/></a>`) and that works exactly as expected within the native Android browser.

However, when the app loads the embedded page (using a WebView) and I click the `tel:` link, I get the "Web page not available" screen ("The Web page at tel:123456 might be temporarily down or it may...").

I assume I need to handle the protocol in the app somehow but I'm not sure how.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to manually handle this, you have to add `WebViewClient` to your webpage and then you have to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and then you have to extract phone number from url then fire intent for phone call, Hope this help...